# Represent string as an integer in python

Tags: python, string, encoding

I would like to be able to represent any string as a unique integer (means every integer in the world could mean only one string, and a certain string would result constantly in the same integer).

The obvious point is, that's how the computer works, representing the string `'Hello'` (for example) as a number for each character, specifically a byte (assuming `ASCII` encoding).

But... I would like to perform arithmetic calculations over that number (Encode it as a number using `RSA`).

The reason this is getting messy is because assuming I have a bit larger string `'I am an average length string'` I have more characters (29 in this case), and an integer with 29 bytes could come up HUGE, maybe too much for the computer to handle (when coming up with bigger strings...?).

Basically, my question is, how could I do? I wouldn't like to use any module for `RSA`, it's a task I would like to implement myself.

Comment: The concept you are describing is "hashing" This will take a datatype and produce a numeric value. Your requirement that "every integer in the world could mean only one string" is [very difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). In practice, it is more like "I need a hash function where collisions are as unlikely as possible"

Comment: "_an integer with 29 bytes could come up HUGE, maybe too much for the computer to handle_". Don't worry about that. Python can handle integers of any size.

Comment: @CoryKramer Is there no perfect hash function in existence?

Comment: @Herrold It depends, a perfect hash for one set of data may not be perfect for all sets of data. For example it is easy to make a function to hash `['a', 'b', 'c']` and get a unique value for each letter. But say you need a function to make a hash for any string of up to 100 characters? That hash function may no longer be "perfect" and collisions may occur. You'll really have to believe me that this is a very difficult task, like if you could make a "perfect hash" that was fast for all data types, you would literally win a Nobel prize.

Comment: You can use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) for existing hash functionality. Note that existing hash functions, as I mentioned are not guaranteed to be "perfect" but they do their best to minimize collisions while still being fast.

Comment: @Herrold There might be. If you figure it out, be sure to uh, tell somebody. https://xkcd.com/664/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to turn a string into a single number. As you suspected, the number will get very large, but Python can handle integers of any arbitrary size. The usual way of working with encryption is to do individual bytes all at once, but I'm assuming this is only for a learning experience. This assumes a byte string, if you have a Unicode string you can encode to UTF-8 first.

```
num = 0
for ch in my_string:
    num = num << 8 + ord(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above code is not working as well, everytime the output is only 0, This code will definitely work:

```
num = 0
for ch in my_string:
    if "0" <= ch <= "9":
        num = num * 10 +(ord(ch) - ord("0"))
```

Here's a breakdown of the code:

1. `num = 0`: Initializes a variable num to store the final numeric value.
2. `for ch in my_string:`: This is a loop that iterates over each character (ch) in the string my_string.
3. `if "0" <= ch <= "9":`: This conditional statement checks if the current character ch is a numeric digit. The condition "0" <= ch <= "9" is True if ch is a digit between '0' and '9' (inclusive).
4. `num = num * 10 + (ord(ch) - ord("0"))`: If the condition in the previous step is True, it means ch is a numeric digit. This line of code then updates the num variable by multiplying its current value by 10 (shifting digits to the left) and adding the numeric value of the current digit.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Please always provide an explanation for the code you write, even if seems trivial.